# NOT LIKE not working with SHOW

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

```
SHOW TABLES NOT LIKE 'wp_2_%'
```

this sql query is not working for me

Comment: is this a query ?

Comment: Which dbms and interface are you using. SQL itself has no SHOW command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `not like` directly in a `show tables` statement, but you could put it in a `where` clause:

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE tables_in_db NOT LIKE 'wp_2_%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it shouldn't work. `SHOW TABLES` simply does not allow using `NOT` like that.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html